# I don't want the else part in tertiary operator

Tags: javascript, class, dom

```
function clear_error(id){
    (document.getElementById(id) != undefined) ? (document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "") : console.log('span is not created yet');
}
```

I have to check that a span element has been created/defined for my error or not, if it is created then remove the inner text for the new error if not then do nothing, as i have made an error function of it in the specified class.

Comment: Why not simply using `if`? You aren't using the return value of your ternary anyway...

Comment: I agreed but I want the code in minimum lines possible.

Comment: Then use a single-line `if`. But in general "minimum lines possible" is a bad idea, code needs to be readablenajd maintainable and that's usually a conflicting goal to "minimum lines possible".

Comment: One of the shortest ways would probably be `const clear_error = id => (document.getElementById(id) ?? {}).innerHTML = ''` but I think it's confusing to read...

Answer (score 2):

A ternary isn't the best tool here. Typically the conditional operator (`? :`) is used when you want to evaluate a condition and obtain a new value based on whether the condition is true/false. You can could `&&` to short-circuit:

```
function clear_error(id) {
  const elem = document.getElementById(id); // store the element to avoid re-querying the DOM
  elem && elem.innerHTML = "";
}
```

but that to me doesn't read very well, so a standard if-statement would work better in my opinion:

```
function clear_error(id){
  const elem = document.getElementById(id); // store the element to avoid re-querying the DOM
  if(elem) {
    elem.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `null` :

```
(document.getElementById('jj') != undefined) ? (document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "") : null
```